# Kali Linux No Sound

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, kali-linux

I mistakenly removed The ALSA config because of this guide http://hackerzelite.blogspot.in/2014/03/fix-sound-driver-on-kali-linux.html. There is now no sound icon, as well no sound.

If I try to install the ALSA package from terminal I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base alsa-base-udeb alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss 

alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsa-utils-udeb alsamixergui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package alsa-base is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'alsa-base' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package alsa-base-udeb
E: Unable to locate package alsa-firmware-loaders
E: Unable to locate package alsa-oss
E: Unable to locate package alsa-source
E: Unable to locate package alsa-tools-gui
E: Unable to locate package alsa-utils
E: Unable to locate package alsa-utils-udeb
E: Unable to locate package alsamixergui
```

sources.list

```
## Regular repositories
deb http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali main non-free contrib 
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ kali/updates main contrib non-free 
## Source repositories
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali main non-free contrib 
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: I don't know Kali, but since it's a Debian derivative it cannot be that different from Ubuntu. It must have been present on your installation disc, so insert it and make sure that that it is enabled in your repositories, then try again.

Comment: not sure what you meant, yes I do have Kali-linux bootable USB

Comment: Don't you have a GUI to display your repository? It is available in `sudo software-properties-gtk`, if you have this or can install it. Or at a lower level you can edit the repository directly in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You should find commented-out entries for your installation disc: remove the leading `#`.

Comment: The install CD is not included in the list: does `sources.list` have commented-out lines beginning with `# deb cdrom: ...`? If not, you can google `kali repository alsa-base`, etc. This gave me [this link](http://repo.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/alsa-base/), which gives the `.deb` files you can down-load and install.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get them from a repo, you have to get them from [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Download) and build it from source.

Comment: ` sudo make install
rm -f /snd*.*o /persist.o /isapnp.o
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/alsa-driver-1.0.9/acore'
Makefile:6: /usr/src/alsa-driver-1.0.9/Makefile.conf: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/alsa-driver-1.0.9/Makefile.conf'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/al`